# Perform password grant auth for Azure AD user with MFA

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, passwords, multi-factor-authentication

I want to enable permissions for a particular user using password grant type.
But that user is MFA enabled as per my tenant policies.
Is it still possible to generate access token for that user from behind a service for only delegated permission ?Thank you

- Aarushi

Comment: From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/authentication-flows-app-scenarios#desktop-app-that-calls-a-web-api-on-behalf-of-a-signed-in-user): "Using the username/password flow constrains your applications. For instance, applications can't sign in a user who needs to use multifactor authentication or the Conditional Access tool in Azure AD. Your applications also don't benefit from single sign-on. Authentication with the username/password flow goes against the principles of modern authentication and is provided only for legacy reasons."

Comment: In [ROPC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) If users need to use multi-factor authentication (MFA) to log in to the application, they will be blocked instead.    Note:Microsoft recommends you do not use the ROPC flow. In most scenarios, more secure alternatives are available and recommended. This flow requires a very high degree of trust in the application, and carries risks which are not present in other flows. You should only use this flow when other more secure flows can't be used.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good post from a few years back on why not to use ROPG, one of which is that it will only ever support a single form of login (not MFA):

- [Resource Owner Password Grant Problems](https://www.scottbrady91.com/OAuth/Why-the-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-Grant-Type-is-not-Authentication-nor-Suitable-for-Modern-Applications)
- [OAuth 2.1 will Drop Support for ROPG](https://fusionauth.io/blog/2020/04/15/whats-new-in-oauth-2-1)

Maybe if you explain your requirements we can suggest a solution that uses a more future facing flow ...